# Google Chart Image does not load

Tags: google-visualization, qr-code

Im using Google charts to create a QR Code. It produces the QR Code perfectly when i just paste the link directly on the browser. However, i cannot get it to load as an image. I get a 400 Error Response.

```
i.e.: http://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/Test%3Fsecret%3DGVFXGN3WIYZEMYKW
```

pasted directly in the browser works but how can i get it to show as an image?

What am i doing wrong?

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/AEB+Staff+Benefits%3Fsecret%3DGVFXGN3WIYZEMYKW" width="200" height="200" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [400 Bad Request when attempting to insert QR code image for Google Authenticator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071368/400-bad-request-when-attempting-to-insert-qr-code-image-for-google-authenticator)

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL-encode the `/`'s (code `%2F`) in the `chl` parameter of the URL:

```
http://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth:%2F%2Ftotp%2FTest%3Fsecret%3DGVFXGN3WIYZEMYKW
```

Comment: Yep. Did that. And had to do a curl fetch and then base64 encode it to show as an image.